# Adding Storyboard to Github project

Tags: ios, xcode, github, uistoryboard

I have a project from github that does not contain storyboards, but I want to add storyboards to see the product before I run the application in the simulator. Can anyone explain how to add a storyboard so I can see how the application will look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html) document from apple will give you all the info you need.